# Aptana Studio 3: Using German umlauts causing errors

Tags: html, character-encoding, aptana, diacritics, aptana3

I just installed Aptana studio 3 and I like it very much. But when I try to use German umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü) in HTML I get the following errors:

- replacing illegal character code 139
- replacing illegal character code 159

How do I avoid these errors? I changed `Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding` to `ISO-8859-1` and also set `meta charset="ISO-8859-1"` in my HTML.

Any ideas? UTF-8 didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error/warning appears to be coming from HTMLTidy. You have two options:

1. You can turn HTMLTidy off (Preferences > Studio > Validation > HTML)
2. You can filter out those errors (Same preference page, add filter ".*illegal character code.*")

See http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Problems+View for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed in the upcoming 3.0.3 update.